# Have gdb step on s immediately

Tags: gdb

I am doing a lot of bug-hunting tonight and it's on a remote machine where I have to use terminal gdb, i.e. no GUI.

Is there a way to tell gdb to step on s (no return press required) and next on n (no return press required as well)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in the TUI "single key mode".  You can enter the TUI with `tui enable` and enter single-key mode by typing `C-x s`.